# Barriers to separating other complexity classes

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Do Natural Proofs, Relativization and Algebrization also affect separation of other complexity classes like $L\neq NL\neq NP\neq coNP \neq PH\neq PSPACE$ etc?

Comment: What research have you done on your own?  What do you already know about the subject?  What do you mean by "also"?

Comment: For instance one way functions do not fall below $NL$ or above $NP$ and $IP$ has been shown to be $PSPACE$ with algebrization.

Comment: Wouldn't Natural proofs apply to $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{co}-\mathsf{NP}$? As that would imply $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$?

Comment: @NicholasMancuso I do not know